# copy data from scaleway/aws s3 to google cloud

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I am trying to copy files/folder from scaleway(object storage bucket) to google cloud bucket using gsutil

> gsutil cp -R s3://scaleway-bucket gs://cloud-storage-bucket

and I am getting error :

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 InvalidAccessKeyId
```

`InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.

I have checked .boto file for the access and secret keys, entries are correct.

I think either I am missing something or doing it incorrectly.

Thanks.

Comment: How have you configured your access and secret keys?

Comment: Yes, I have configured them in ~/.aws/credentials file. It did not worked, so I have added those in .boto file. but getting the same error

Comment: Now, I have generated another token for new accessID and secret key and added these to .boto file. getting another error, 

ServiceException: 301 The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.


I have added region and endpoint URL : 

[plugins]
endpoint = awscli_plugin_endpoint

region = nl-ams
s3 =
  endpoint_url = https://s3.nl-ams.scw.cloud
  max_concurrent_requests = 100
  max_queue_size = 1000


still getting the same error.

Comment: somehow I think I am able to configure endpoint too..

now, the new issue is, getting error : 

ResumableUploadAbortException: 401 Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.create access to cloud-storage-bucket.

Answer (score 1):

I have uninstalled/removed and reinstalled gcloud and gsutil. It worked for me.

Thanks.